# Can't highlight words in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, colors, gnome-terminal, highlighting

I have been using the gnome Terminal for 3 months already, but today I can't highlight the words on the terminal suddenly. I can't do so on nedit as well. When I use the 'find' function in nedit to find a keyword, it scrolls to the right place but it doesn't highlight the word. Has anyone ever encountered this before?

Update1: when I press my mouse and move over text on nedit, I can highlight the text temporarily, but the text isn't highlighted anymore if I keep pressing and don't move

Comment: You say you cant select text in terminal using the mouse cursor?

Comment: Is the text selected but not highlighted, i.e. can you use the selection as if it was highlighted? If so, there might be an issue with colours or the `TERM` setting.

Comment: I can highlight the text when the left button of my mouse is pressed, but when I release the button, it is not highlighted anymore as if nothing has happened

Comment: Is the terminal also running `screen` or `tmux`? Does pressing shift or alt make it work?

Comment: I guess you have some app (may be part of the DE) which is "stealing" the selection. There are a lot of crappy little kludges floating around, all of them severly broken, supposed to "fix" (disable) the middle button pasting or to "streamline" the cut&pasting -- but I've never used any of them; I'm sorry I cannot help you with more, but If you're using any of them, disable it.

Comment: @Kusalananda no I don't think so;hmm no, I have tried pressing ctrl, alt and shift separately while pressing the left button of my mouse, but it doesn't work

Comment: @pizdelect I'm not so sure, I was running questasim, vncconfig and nedit only. I have been using them for months. My colleagues have been using them for years and they have never seen such a situation before

Comment: @hk56740 it can be part of the DE (gnome). To eliminate all doubt, try running another Xorg server (eg. `Xephyr :1`), run `nedit` in it (`DISPLAY=:1 nedit`), and see if it behaves the same.

Comment: _hk56740_, when you respond to comments, please do not make another comment; instead, click on [edit] and enhance your original question by expanding it to address the comment. That way, everyone can see your response.